# CREATE FUNCTION IN SQL select into

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I'm trying to create the following function, but I can't

```
CREATE function pse_consecutivosiif (
    @empresa NUMERIC
    , @comprobante NUMERIC
    , @tercero NUMERIC
) 
returns NUMERIC
as    
BEGIN
    DECLARE i_consecutividad NUMERIC(5);

    select max(consecutividad) 
    into i_consecutividad
    from (
        select hojaIdenti cedula
            , dense_rank() over (order by  hojaIdenti) as consecutividad
        FROM movimiento MO
        INNER JOIN VISTADOS VIS ON MO.identifica = VIS.identifica
            AND MO.empresa = VIS.empresa
        WHERE MO.comprobante = @comprobante
            AND  MO.empresa = @empresa
    )
    where cedula = @tercero
    );

return i_consecutividad;
end;
```

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: I removed the `oracle` tag as this is clearly SQL Server only

Comment: Why can't you? Include the error message to help triage the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Point to note:

1. You need to declare variable starting with @
2. Assignment is not like select into but like in following code
3. Always need to provide table name if creating using subquery

Find working function below

```
 CREATE function pse_consecutivosiif ( @empresa NUMERIC, @comprobante NUMERIC, @tercero NUMERIC) 
    returns NUMERIC
    as

    BEGIN
    DECLARE @i_consecutividad NUMERIC(5);

    select @i_consecutividad=max(consecutividad) 
     from (select hojaIdenti cedula, dense_rank() over (order by  hojaIdenti) as consecutividad
     FROM movimiento MO INNER JOIN VISTADOS VIS ON MO.identifica = VIS.identifica 
                                                                           AND MO.empresa = VIS.empresa
                                WHERE MO.comprobante = @comprobante
                                AND  MO.empresa = @empresa) y
    where y.cedula = @tercero


    return @i_consecutividad;
    end;
```

Comment: And a superfluous final bracket I believe?

Comment: "provide table name" - table alias.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what the purpose of your procedure is. However, here is an updated version that does compile properly in SQL Server.

```
create function pse_consecutivosiif (@empresa numeric, @comprobante numeric, @tercero numeric) 
returns numeric
as
begin
    declare @i_consecutividad numeric;
    select @i_consecutividad = max(consecutividad) 
    from (
        select 
            hojaidenti,
            cedula, 
            dense_rank() over (order by  hojaidenti) as consecutividad
        from movimiento mo 
        inner join vistados vis on mo.identifica = vis.identifica and mo.empresa = vis.empresa
        where mo.comprobante = @comprobante
        and  mo.empresa = @empresa
    ) t
    where cedula = @tercero;

    return @i_consecutividad;
end;
```

Changes to your original code:

- the variable should be declared with a leading `@`
- you assign a value to the variable with `=` in the `select` clause of the query; `select ... into ...` is meant to create a new table, not to assign to a scalar variable
- the subquery requires an alias
- there is a superfluous closing parenthese at the end of the code
- proper formating and indentation make the code easier to read

Comment: THANKSSSS!!!!!!! that's the answer!!!!! I  need to put an "alias" in the subquery. Thank you so much!